# how to add button table column using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>table with sparkline</title>
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
<style>
.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.0px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
th{
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
}
/*tr:hover{background-color:#f5f5f5}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h4>a table</h4>
<div id="table"></div>
<script>
var columns = ['Fruit', 'Color', 'Lines']

var data = [
    ['Orange', 'Orange', [1,2,3,1,6]],
    ['Apple', 'Red', [6,2,6,5,5]],
    ['Grape', 'Purple', [9,1,2,3,1]]
]

// create table
var table = d3.select("#table").append("table");

var thead = table.append("thead").append("tr");

thead.selectAll("th")
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append("th")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d;
    });

var tbody = table.append("tbody");

var trows = tbody
    .selectAll("tr")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("tr");

var tcells = trows
    .selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d, i) { return d; })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .text(function(d, i) { return d; });

// update (add a column with graphs)
thead.append("th").text('Graphs');

trows.selectAll("td.graph")  
//use a class so you don't re-select the existing <td> elements
          .data(function(d) {return [d[2]];})
          .enter()
            .append("td")
            .attr("class", "graph")
            .each(lines); 


// a sparklines plot
function lines(test) {  
    var width = 100, height = 20; 

    var data = []
    for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        data[i] = {
            'x': i,
            'y': +test[i]
        }
    }
    
    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, width - 10])
        .domain([0,5]);
    
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0])
        .domain([0,10]);
    
    var line = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) {return x(d.x)})
                .y(function(d) {return y(d.y)});
    
    d3.select(this).append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
         .append('path')
            .attr('class','line')
            .datum(data)
            .attr('d', line);     

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my code..i have created table using d3.js..here i just want to add button in column.how to add button in column for each row??
and if i click the button it will show the alert message
here i have used data in json format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make a header.

```
thead.append("th").text('Action');
```

Then to the rows add selector and pass the data, create a `td` then on that `td` make a `button` and then finally register a listener for click.

```
trows.selectAll("td.button")  
//use a class so you don't re-select the existing <td> elements
          .data(function(d) {return [d];})
          .enter()
            .append("td")
            .attr("class", "button")
            .append("button")
            .text(function(d){return "Do Something"})
            .on("click", function(d){ console.log(d); alert("hello")});//attach listener
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HBdwPdbkRR30l8Mj1vyq?p=info)

Comment: how to access particular row when i click that row button?

Comment: i mean if click first row button ,i have to alert that rows data

Comment: check the console `console.log(d);` here d is that row's data

Comment: Or i have added the row's data in the alert check the plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/6snKLi4QIyZOt7H1p9Dq?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Append button to your cell class:

```
 var button = $("<button>Button</button>");
 button.click(function() {
    alert("here i have used data in json format : "+JSON.stringify(data));
 });
 button.appendTo(".graph");
```

Here is a working example http://jsbin.com/xogawac/edit?html,output

Comment: i have to make as a column

Comment: i have to create one column that column contains this button

Comment: then if i click 1st row button means it shows alert message as that rows data

Comment: @SaiRajesh I think Cyril has answered it perfectly.